# Formula vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code, the formula for all rows is fixed and takes into account g3, while each row must change G3. For example, in row 4, G4 should be recorded in the formula.

How can G be inserted according to each row in the formula.

```
sub n()

    IFor n = 3 To 916
        If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(n, "A")) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(n, "A").Formula = "=diff(shamsi(),g3)/30"
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Use .FormulaR1C1 or use the iterator in the formula string.

Comment: Sounds like a formula is enough, no need to use VBA macro. You'd better post several origin rows and what is expected to make your question more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

### Write Formulas

**A Quick Fix**

- The simplest way in this particular case is to use R1C1-style referencing as suggested by Skin in the comments:

  ```
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, "A").FormulaR1C1 = "=diff(shamsi(),RC[6])/30"
  ```

  where `R` means the same row, while `C[6]` means 6 columns to the right relative to each source cell.

**An Improvement**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteFormulas()
 
    ' Reference the range.
 
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A3:A916")
      
    ' Combine the critical cells into a unioned range.
      
    Dim urg As Range, cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In rg.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = cel Else Set urg = Union(urg, cel)
        End If
    Next cel
    
    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write the formula (in one go).
    
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    FirstAddress = urg.Cells(1).EntireRow.Columns("G").Address(0, 0)
    
    urg.Formula = "=diff(shamsi()," & FirstAddress & ")/30"
    ' Or as Skin suggested in the comments:
    'urg.FormulaR1C1 = "=diff(shamsi(),RC[6])/30"
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```